# how to use or(||) in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a functions want to trigger if whether first button clicked or second button clicked don't know syntax to write it

Comment: choose one: do the entire job with js or setup an ajax based call to a php script that return the data you need;

Comment: You can create an hidden select with php and then clone and append it with js ( change id before append ) .... this work only if the select options don't change during page life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your function and add it to the buttons click event.

```
function yourFunc(){
    //the code
}
$("#firstButId").click(yourFunc);
$("#secondButId").click(yourFunc);
```

Btw, I wrote this cause it was short but the Stack Overflow philosofy encourages you to make research, try it yourself and then come here and ask when you can't find a solution for your problem. Rather than just come and ask us to make code for you.